# Bongard Problem 3

Tags: pattern, bongard

*Find the rule that is correct on the left side, but not on the right side.* If you don't know about bongard problems you can [click here.](http://www.foundalis.com/res/diss_research.html)

[image: bongard3]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the left side

> There are an even number of enclosed spaces, I believe.

On the right side,

> There are an odd number of enclosed regions.

Comment: Correct. Going to wait some minutes before I can accept.